# Git adding previously "Ignored" file in repo is not working

Tags: git

The question is for Windows OS. I need to add a previously ignored directly (and all files inside) to my repo. So, I went away and updated my `.gitignore`, committed my changes and merged them into the main branch. But when i do git status, I don't see my directory in "Untracked" list of files. In other words, git is still ignoring them even when `.gitignore` is updated.

When I went inside `.git/info/exclude` file - it looks like the data is being cached. Is there any cleaner way to update this list without manually hacking it?

KR,

Comment: *"When I went inside `.git/info/exclude` file - it looks like the data is being cached."* -- `.git/info/exclude` is not a cache. It is a project-specific private exclusion file. You and only you (and not Git) write it.

Comment: @axiac         omg  aaaarrgghhh!!!! when i was using this for the first time must of added this back then!!! totally forgot :(  okay so I can just delete that file? and Eureka?

Comment: You can delete it or you can remove from it the patterns that you don't need there. It has the same format as `.gitignore` but it is not shared with anybody; each clone of the repo has one that starts empty (all it contains are several lines of comments on top). Read more about [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore); it is also explained the role of `.git/info/exclude`.

Comment: `git check-ignore <path>` tells by which setting the path is ignored. `git add -f <path>` tracks the path even if it's ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `.git/info/exclude` (`$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` to be correct) is one of the files read by Git when it comes to exclude files from tracking.

It is a project-specific, personal exclusion file. It is not shared with the other clones of the repo.
Read more about in the documentation page of [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

Yours probably contains by mistake the patterns you just removed from `.gitignore`. Those patterns should not be there in the first place, but only in `.gitignore`.

As the documentation says:

> Patterns which are specific to a particular repository but which do not need to be shared with other related repositories (e.g., auxiliary files that live inside the repository but are specific to one user’s workflow) should go into the `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` file.

For example, if you are using a JetBrains product to develop the code and everybody else uses Eclipse, you can put `.idea` into your `.git/info/exclude` to avoid adding the IDE's specific files to the repo and to avoid cluttering `.gitignore` with patterns that are not related to the project itself.
(Of course, you better add `.idea` in the global `.gitignore` file but this is another story.)